# Xamarin.Android - Error - Implementing AlarmManager.IOnAlarmListener

Tags: alarmmanager

I get the following error while running the code on an Emulator - MArshmallow. 
Please let me know what could be the reason.

When I implement other Interface like IServiceConnection, the code does not throw error.

```
namespace ExampleNameSpace
{  
    public class TestAlarmListener : Java.Lang.Object, 
    AlarmManager.IOnAlarmListener
    {
        public TestAlarmListener(){}
        public void OnAlarm(){ }
    }

    [Activity(Label = "AlarmActivity")]
    public class AlarmActivity : Activity
    {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Alarm);
            TestAlarmListener listener = new TestAlarmListener();

        }


    Error -

     06-01 18:05:25.557: E/AppMessage(8848): Didn't find class 
    "md5d67d3b9255c5c503bc35ab778230d3db.TestAlarmListener" on path: 
    DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ExampleApp.ExamplePack-
   1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ExampleApp.ExamplePack-
   1/lib/arm, /data/app/ExampleApp.ExamplePack-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, 
    /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: I got the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: I found the answer you have to implement 2 more constructors and compile with an API > 19 here is my alarm listener

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer you have to implement 2 more constructors and compile with an API > 19 here is my alarm listener

```
public class Test :Java.Lang.Object, AlarmManager.IOnAlarmListener
{

    public Test ()
    {

    }
    public Test(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
    }
    public Test(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
    {
    }
    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void OnAlarm()
    {
        Log.Info("AlarmToastReceiver", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```